# Do I need to add something special in order to see my site properly on iPad?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ipad

I have built a website(asp.net): http://avior-ins.co.il/
I can view the site on my computer(I have checked Firefox, safari, chrome and explorer and everything's OK), but the customer says that the CSS seems to be defective when he use iPad.

I don't own an iPad/iPhone, but I don't see any problem when I use my android phone(Motorola droid razr). I have also checked the site http://ipadpeek.com/, which is supposed to be a kind of iPad emulator and I don't see any problem.

Will you please check the site from Ipad and tell me what can cause the bug?

Thanks from advance!

Comment: I've opened your site on iPad and see that background image is not rendering properly. It's hard to say the root cause of this. I see that you set width in pixels for aspNetHidden (width: 1280px;). Can you replace it with percents? Or just decrease it to 800px?

Comment: I didn't set the width for "aspNetHidden", I set the with for "siteContainer". I think I'll try 100% and see if it helps, the iPad resolution is 800px?

Comment: iPad resolution is 1024 x 768.

Comment: that's ipad2.  ipad3 (or just "ipad" as they're calling it) is double that.  go with percentages.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cant see if things help on iPad... :/
Can someone tell me if changing the with to 100% does the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help. The real problem was an  tag with text-indent -9999px.
It was placed on the site's menu and when I removed it, I looked ok.

Answer (score 1):

In case you run into too much trouble developing a one-size-fits-all web page, you can have an ipad version of the page and then use detect/redirect strategy.

http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad

This fellow has a few nice approaches to that already worked-out.

Comment: I would prefer not to develop a site for iPad, because I have no design for it. Maybe I can just add an option to scroll the page when the resolution is too low?